# How to respond with an HTTP 204 in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

I have a system use spring integration to exchange data.
AppClient request AppServer with a TableInfoRequest and AppServer will response a TableInfoResponse.It work fine now.

```
    

    @MessagingGateway()
    public interface SyncGateway {

      @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestFlow.input")
      TableInfoResponse info(TableInfoRequest payload);

    }
```

**But I want to respond with an http code 204 when no data to response that will reduce the data in response. So how can I set DSL?**

```
    @Bean
      public IntegrationFlow syncFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
              Http.inboundGateway(HTTP_ENDPOINT_PATH).id("syncGateway")
                .replyTimeout(serverProps.getReplyTimeout() * 1000)
                .requestTimeout(serverProps.getRequestTimeout() * 1000)
                .messageConverters(new SerializingHttpMessageConverter())
                .convertExceptions(true)
                .mappedResponseHeaders(IDENTIFICATION, TOKEN))
            .channel(c -> c.direct("syncChannel")
                .interceptor(new ChannelAuthenticationInterceptor(dataService)))
            .handle(syncHandler)
            .get();
      }
```

The syncHandler will return TableInfoResponse.And AppClient use *syncGateway.info(request)* to get tableInfoResponse.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` header (`http_statusCode`) in the reply message.

Comment: In other words if you want to return `204 No Content` reply, you should really do that - reply to the Inbond Gateway with the `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-response-statuscode

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I don't understand how to reply 204 when no data. `.handle(syncHandler)` will also reply a object.And AppClient also want receive a object - `.expectedResponseType(Serializable.class)`

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
 .statusCodeFunction(m -> HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
```

e.g.

```
@Bean
      public IntegrationFlow syncFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
              Http.inboundGateway(HTTP_ENDPOINT_PATH).id("syncGateway")
                .replyTimeout(serverProps.getReplyTimeout() * 1000)
                .requestTimeout(serverProps.getRequestTimeout() * 1000)
                .statusCodeFunction(m -> HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
                .messageConverters(new SerializingHttpMessageConverter())
                .convertExceptions(true)
                .mappedResponseHeaders(IDENTIFICATION, TOKEN))
            .channel(c -> c.direct("syncChannel")
                .interceptor(new ChannelAuthenticationInterceptor(dataService)))
            .handle(syncHandler)
            .get();
      }
```